# How to create delegate for QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qt4, qtreewidget

Here is what I'm trying to do (all parents and children must have a **close** button on the right, in the future, only the hovered item will be able to show the **close ** button):

[image]

**My delegate code:**

```
class CloseButton : public QItemDelegate
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     CloseButton( QObject* parent = 0 )
          : QItemDelegate( parent )
     {};

     QWidget* createEditor( QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
     {
          if ( index.column() == 1 )
          {
               QToolButton* button = new QToolButton( parent );
               button->setIcon( QIcon( CLOSE_ICON ) );
               //button->setFixedSize( 16, 16 );
               //button->setAutoRaise( true );
               //button->setVisible( true );

               CONNECT( button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( emitCommitData() ) );

               return button;
          }
          return ( new QWidget );
     }

private slots:
     void emitCommitData()
     {
          emit commitData( qobject_cast< QWidget* >( sender() ) );
     }

private:
     //Q_DISABLE_COPY( CloseButton );
};
```

**With `QTreeWidget` connection code:**

```
recipientsView()->setItemDelegateForColumn( 1, new CloseButton( this ) );
```

where `recipientsView()` is a simple `QTreeWidget`.

Problem is that `QToolButton`s are not shown at all (it must be in the second column, i.e. column index in the tree is `1`). What I'm doing wrong?

I have checked already all Qt demo examples about delegates and  the first Google result about `QItemDelegate`'s and similar stuff.

Comment: In VS2008 debugger constructor executes, but `createEditor()` method are not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `QStyledDelegate::paint` function to draw the close icon, without using any widget, and the `editorEvent` to receive mouse events for the item, even if you don't use the editor or make the item editable.

```
class CloseButton : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit CloseButton(QObject *parent = 0, 
                         const QPixmap &closeIcon = QPixmap())
        : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
        , m_closeIcon(closeIcon)
    {
        if(m_closeIcon.isNull())
        {
            m_closeIcon = qApp->style()
                ->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DialogCloseButton);
        }
    }

    QPoint closeIconPos(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option) const {
        return QPoint(option.rect.right() - m_closeIcon.width() - margin,
                      option.rect.center().y() - m_closeIcon.height()/2);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        // Only display the close icon for top level items...
        if(!index.parent().isValid()
                // ...and when the mouse is hovering the item
                // (mouseTracking must be enabled on the view)
                && (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver))
        {
            painter->drawPixmap(closeIconPos(option), m_closeIcon);
        }
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QSize size = QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);

        // Make some room for the close icon
        if(!index.parent().isValid()) {
            size.rwidth() += m_closeIcon.width() + margin * 2;
            size.setHeight(qMax(size.height(),
                                m_closeIcon.height() + margin * 2));
        }
        return size;
    }

    bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                     const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                     const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        // Emit a signal when the icon is clicked
        if(!index.parent().isValid() &&
                event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
            QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

            QRect closeButtonRect = m_closeIcon.rect()
                    .translated(closeIconPos(option));

            if(closeButtonRect.contains(mouseEvent->pos()))
            {
                emit closeIndexClicked(index);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

signals:
    void closeIndexClicked(const QModelIndex &);
private:
    QPixmap m_closeIcon;
    static const int margin = 2; // pixels to keep arount the icon

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(CloseButton)
};
```

Comment: alexisdm, I must say, that your code works great! This is really perfect for me solution of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

First, I should ask if you are really using a QTreeWidget, or rather a QTreeView? You cannot use custom delegates with a QTreeWidget according to the documentation for QTreeView, and will have to use a QTree*View* and some form of QAbstractItemModel for you to be able to use a custom delegate.

Ah, scratch that. I see that you're calling setItemDelegateForColumn, which is a QTreeView function, but you should be aware of the difference, so I'm keeping the above paragraph. :)

I would check that your model's [flags()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) function is returning Qt::ItemIsEditable as part of its item flags. The createEditor() method is called whenever an edit event is reported by the view. (The view events that will trigger an edit depend on the model's EditTriggers) Usually a double-click on the delegate will trigger an edit by default, among other things.

I doubt that you want the close button to appear only on double-click, though. To get the button to appear all the time, you'll have to reimplement the delegate's paint() function to draw a button, Among other things. I found Qt's [StarDelegate example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-stardelegate.html) to be quite helpful in this regard, and I suspect you'll find it useful too.

Comment: Thnx, first of all! And answering your question - yes, I'm using `QTreeWidget`! But, maybe your are right about theme, that custom delegate can't be used with `QTreeWidget`, but what about example? I mean in *StarDelegate example* `QTableWidget` successfully used with custom delegate?! How that can be?

Comment: And about migration from `QTreeWidget` to `QTreeView`: in my case, MVC is not the right way, because, I'm using this widget, I mean `QTreeWidget`, to hold on just 4-5 rows, 1-2 parents, and thats all, it's the, so called, recipients list, not the address book...

Comment: I suppose that the documentation is inaccurate in that regard. (About the impossibility of using a custom delegate with an item-based view.) QTreeWidget and freinds are based off of the QTreeView classes (only offering a simplified interface for using QTreeItems), so it does appear that you can set custom delegates and such.

At any rate you'll still probably need to take a look at the paint() function of the delegate. If you did a setFlags(flags() |= Qt::ItemIsEditable) on each of the items in the second column, your existing code would probably display the toolbutton on a double click.

Comment: You know, when I set `ItemIsEditable` flag, strange things began to happen. Close button appeared in separate window! %) I used variant of creating `QToolButton` with out a parent that time. But when I set to button parent widget, no button was visible at all... I guess, that it's easier to create a f*cking button widget, and set it to all `QTreeWidgetItem`'s with `setIndexWidget`... As I become to understand, delegates are needed for editing purposes, but not just for drawing widget in trees/tables...  All day I waste my time with this stuff! Any way thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a QItemDelegate with a QTreeWidget this way (example in PyQt, sorry):

```
myTreeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
myTreeWidget.setItemDelegate(myDelegate())

class myDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        #Custom Draw Column 1
        if index.column() == 1:
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole))
            if icon:
                icon.paint(painter, option.rect)
                #You'll probably want to pass a different QRect

        #Use the standard routine for other columns
        else:
            super(myDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
```