# How to use custom widget with events/signals as QStyledItemDelegates?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to make a QStyledItemDelegate behave like a custom QWidget I wrote, so I can switch my code to a model/view approach.

The custom QWidget is a complex button which shows four "sub buttons" in it's corners on mouse over (so all in all there are five signals). It's also drag&droppable with a custom drag pixmap. To achieve this I am using mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent, mouseMoveEvent, enterEvent and leaveEvent. This is what it looks like with and without the "sub buttons" shown on mouse over:
[image]

I have since switched my main code to use a model/view approach and am trying to use this widget as a QStyledItemDelegate for my customised ListView.
I have tried assigning the custom Widget as an editor like this:

```
class ToolButtonDelegate( QStyledItemDelegate ):

    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( ToolButtonDelegate, self).__init__( parent )
        self.parent = parent

    def createEditor( self, parent, option, index ):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        btn = FancyButton( index.data( Qt.UserRole ), parent=parent )
        return btn
```

This seems promising as it draws the "FancyButton" class for the item I click on. However, I need this to be a mouse over event.
After a bit more research I tried connecting the QAbstractItemView.entered slot to QAbstractItemView.edit signal:

```
self.entered.connect( self.edit )
```

This works only for the first item I move my mouse pointer over, then I get these errors:

```
edit: editing failed
```

So now I'm stuck again with these problems:

- how to properly close the editor (there is no "QAbstractItemView.leave" event or similar).
- how to ensure that the mouse clicks actually trigger the buttons in the FanyButton class rather than just interact with the QAbstractIremView

I have a feeling I'm heading into the wrong direction here.

Comment: drag&drop obviously works, but I don't see a way to assign any of those event filters. E.g. how can I catch a mouse enter and leave event for an item in a model/view structure?

Comment: Anybody? I'm a bit stuck with this one now. I basically need to draw an existing custom widget with all it's mouse events into (or as) an item delegate. I have mouse over effects and drag&drop working on the widget but no idea how to use it in my view as a delegate now.

Comment: @FrankRueter So what about posting your solution as acceptable answer? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd urge you to go back to delegates instead of widgets, purely for performance reasons =)

You can work with delegates mouse over events in paint method using states, particularly QStyle::State_MouseOver. As for clicks on buttons you can override editorEvent which receives all mouse events and then work with regions of where mouse clicks occurred. For example:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
    {
        // draw stuff which appears on mouse over
    } else {
        // draw stuff that appears when mouse is not over control
    }
 }

bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel*, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
        // Emit a signal when the icon is clicked
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            QRect editButtonRect = editIcon.rect().translated(editIconPos(option));
            QRect deleteButtonRect = deleteIcon.rect().translated(deleteIconPos(option));

            if(editButtonRect.contains(mouseEvent->pos()))
            {
                emit editIndexClicked(index);
            } else if (deleteButtonRect.contains(mouseEvent->pos())) {
                emit deleteIndexClicked(index);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also you can check out this topic [HowTo create delegate for QTreeWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175333/howto-create-delegate-for-qtreewidget), this is for QTreeWidget, but I think same methods would apply to your case too.

Comment: thanks, but at this stage I have widgets working with good performance. If it becomes a problem I will look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't use custom widgets for viewing items in a List/Table/Tree-View-delegates. You can use them for editing, but if the view-mode requires anything other than just a redraw, you're pretty stumped.

We've worked around this by having our own container widgets which listen to model events and add/remove item-widgets dynamically. A shame really, since it feels rather basic.

The reason might be that the views are supposed to be fast and able to show a lot of items, and having a lot of widgets isn't fast, so they've chosen to just allow a custom repaint function (which allows them to use justone container widget, with custom painting in different areas.)

Maybe there's a way around it, and if so, I'd be happy to hear about it.

**Update**

If you need to catch events, maybe you can install an event filter to the container view, then use [QListView::indexAt](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#indexAt) to find the right item/widget/delegate to send the event to?

You can then use [openPersistentEditor](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) and closePersistentEditor on mouseenter/leave to enable editing, i.e. show/close your custom widget on an item.

Comment: I've decided to abandon delegates and try and write my own view that uses widgets instead. So far it seems to be working though I'm not quite through the thick yet.