# Qt - What's the corresponding widget to this picture in Qt?

Tags: qt

[image]

When one of the categories is clicked, a list of instances will cascade down and each one is also clickable. Like file manager in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [`QTreeWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) (or [`QTreeView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html)) with custom [`QItemDelegate`s](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html).

See also [HowTo create delegate for QTreeWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175333/howto-create-delegate-for-qtreewidget).

---

In QT Designer, you can edit the contents of the tree widget through the "Edit Items" menu entry from the context menu which opens the "Edit Tree Widget" dialog:

[image]

Comment: How can I insert default categories, like the `TCP Server`, `TCP Client` above,  to the Tree View with Qt designer ??

Comment: My bad, I tried tree view instead and found it cannot add items. Tree widget can. Thanks a lot !